# How trigger error/which validator to use in Angular2 template-driven form to check whether an input field has no value

Tags: html, angular

How can I trigger an error, or which form validator do I use in an Angular2 template-driven form, to check whether an input field's value is null/empty regardless of whether it has been touched? I want all inputs to display the relevant error messages when the form loads and there is no data for that specific field (no data returned for that field via an API call).

I was thinking of using something like: `reference.value.null`. But this does not work.

**Here is what I have thus far:**

```
    <label
      [class.error-label]="!idNumber.valid && idNumber.touched"
      for="gender"
      for="id-number"
      class="af-input-label"
      >ID Number</label
    >

    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control af-input"
      id="id-number"
      placeholder="8912130088089"
      ngModel
      name="idNumber"
      required
      #idNumber="ngModel"
    />

<span *ngIf="!idNumber.valid && idNumber.touched" class="error-text">Please fill in your full ID Number</span>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check the official documentation of Angular from https://angular.io/guide/forms#summary . You have a mistake on `ngModel` binding. (You must check hero-form.component.html and ts files.)

Comment: I used ngModel as per the guidelines of the following course; Angular - The Complete Guide (2020 Edition). But I will check out your link thank you.

Comment: It is still using `Angular 6`, so it is not a 2020 edition. `Angular 6.0` released at 2018-05-03.

Comment: Thank you. Will check into that. But even when changing the code regarding the ngModel, I still don't have a solution to my question. :)

Comment: You can see the working example from StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-template-driven-form-validation